# Cannot reference non-static field "x"

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/> gdb a.out
(gdb) watch dummyA::x
Cannot reference non-static field "x"
(gdb)
```

`x` is a private member of a class named *dummyA*.
How to set a watch point on the private member of the class?

*Language: C++

Platform: Linux*

### EDIT 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class dummyA
{
    int x;

    public:
        dummyA ()
        {
            x = 0;
        }

        void test ()
        {
            x++;
        }
};

int main ()
{
    dummyA obj;
    obj.test ();
    obj.test ();
    obj.test ();
}
```

Output:

```
(gdb) watch obj.x
No symbol "obj" in current context.

(gdb) watch obj::x
No symbol "obj" in current context.
```

Now, what does that error mean?

Comment: The error means you have to step past the first line in which `obj` is instantiated. The line that reads `dummyA obj;`.

Comment: @Omnifarious You are right!! Thanks, but what sense does it make? Can I not set the watchpoints at the beginning of the session? Think about putting the reply in your answer (if you can).

Comment: You cannot set watch points on objects that don't exist yet. You can set watchpoints on global variables at the beginning of the session (or at the very least, after a breakpoint on `main` is hit), but nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have this:

```
class A {
 private:
   int x;
}

int main()
{
    A foo;
    A bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Now you have two instances of `A` named `foo` and `bar`. If you tell the debugger to watch `A::x` how does it know which instance you mean?

When you watch an instance variable (of which there is one for each instance) instead of a static variable (of which there is only one for every class) you need to specify which instance's variable you want to watch. You are specifying which class' variable you want to watch. And while that would be OK with a static variable (there is only one static variable per class) it's not OK with an instance variable.

In this case, in `main`, after stepping past the two lines `A foo;` and `A bar;` you could do:

```
watch foo.x
```

or

```
watch bar.x
```

and it would work just fine. You have to step past those lines because not even the names (much less the objects they refer to) exist until after them.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I commented on the question and edited this post.

Comment: Thanks, but `You have to step past those lines because not even the names (much less the objects they refer to) exist until after them.` do we not set the breakpoints on the functions on the very start? We do? How does that work then?

Comment: Well, think about it...  the code for those functions exists at the very start. It's created by the compiler when you compile the program. So its position is known. One way the debugger can set a breakpoint there is by modifying the code at the beginning of the function to cause a signal that it traps. But how can it do anything for a variable that doesn't exist yet? It hasn't been assigned a memory location or anything. There is nothing the debugger can do.

Answer (score 1):

GDB appears to think that this is a *non-static* member, hence you would need an instantiated object to get at it.

Are you *sure* you've marked this class member as `static`? It needs to be static (class-specific rather than object-specific) if you wish to access it via the class.

With the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
class xyzzy { public: int x; };
//int xyzzy::x = 7;
int main (void) {
    xyzzy plugh;
    plugh.x = 42;
    std::cout << plugh.x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

my session is similar to yours:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80485cd: file qq.cpp, line 12.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pax/qq 
Breakpoint 1, main () at qq.cpp:12
12      plugh.x = 42;
(gdb) watch xyzzy::x
Cannot reference non-static field "x"
(gdb)
```

But, when I make `x` static and uncomment the initialiser, I get the more successful:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80485cd: file qq.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pax/qq 
Breakpoint 1, main () at qq.cpp:6
6       plugh.x = 42;
(gdb) watch xyzzy::x
Hardware watchpoint 2: xyzzy::x
```

---

If you want to watch a member of an *object* (rather than class), you have to wait until it's substantiated, such as with:

```
#include <iostream>
class xyzzy { public: int x; };
int main (void) {
    xyzzy plugh;
    plugh.x = 42;
    std::cout << plugh.x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

and the transcript:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80485cd: file qq.cpp, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pax/qq 

Breakpoint 1, main () at qq.cpp:5
5       plugh.x = 42;
(gdb) watch plugh.x
Hardware watchpoint 2: plugh.x
(gdb)
```

Comment: No, I haven't marked anything `static`. x is just a plain private int variable of class dummyA getting initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Presumably you can instantiate several instances of `class A`. And each of these instances will contain its own `x`. How does the debugger know which instance you mean?

Comment: @Anisha, if it's non-static, you have to access it via an object, not the class. Non-static members belong to individual objects.

Comment: `How does the debugger know which instance you mean?` Thanks pax, I realize this now. But I tried it through the object, see the edit, it still doesnt work! What's the point that I am missing?

Comment: @Anisha, `obj` doesn't exist until after the line `dummyA obj` - that's what your new error is complaining about. You need to step through with the debugger until after that statement and _then_ put a watch on the variable.

Comment: Thanks, done that. Doesn't the same apply to functions too? We can set the breakpoints on functions at the very start!

Comment: @Anisha, most functions (barring those that will be dynamically loaded as DLLs) exist at startup. Not all variables exist at startup. GDB even allows for this deferment with a message like `(gdb) b no_such_fn Function "no_such_fn" not defined. Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])?`

Comment: Alright well, thanks, I think I need to read more, and then ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

As `x` is a private member of your class, it's information (and thus its memory location) depends on the object (the `this` pointer) with which you access it.

Thus you need to set your watch somewhere you have a scope-accessible reference to the concerned object (including `this` pointer if you break in a member method).

One other solution may be to use accessors & mutators, and exclusively access your variable through those accessors. Then you'll be able to put a standard breakpoint in the accessors & mutators, which allows you to break on *any* access to private ivar `x`, without object specific information.

Comment: `Thus you need to set your watch somewhere you have a scope-accessible reference to the concerned object (including this pointer if you break in a member method).` Any example for this?